# How can i use "Not in" with ARRAY_CONTAINS in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am New to Cosmos DB. I am retrieving records using SQL API.now i want to add "Not In" in ARRAY_CONTAINS. I did lots of R&D for the same but not able to find out any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add "Not In" in [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery#example-rewriting-array_contains-and-join-as-exists). There is not such syntax in Cosmos DB.

If you want to retrieving the records which donot contain some value. You can use `NOT EXISTS`. For below example

```
SELECT food.id,
    food.description,
    food.tags,
    food.foodGroup
FROM food 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT VALUE t FROM t IN food.tags WHERE t.name = 'orange')
```

Above query will retrive all the food records on the condition "orange" is not in tags. Below is **an example from above query result.**

```
{
  "id": "19015",
  "description": "Snacks, granola bars, hard, plain",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "snacks"
    },
    {
      "name": "granola bars"
    },
    {
      "name": "hard"
    },
    {
      "name": "plain"
    }
  ],
  "foodGroup": "Snacks"
}
```

You can go to the [Query Playground](https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo) of Cosmos DB to learn and practice Cosmos DB querying.

Answer (score 5):

You can add NOT IN simply like below example:

```html
SELECT
    food.id,
    food.description,
    food.tags,
    food.foodGroup
FROM 
  food    
WHERE food.id
NOT IN ('ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3')
```

This is tested and will work like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

This will find all items where the property **resolutions** (which is an array) does not contain the value "600".

```
SELECT VALUE root FROM root WHERE (NOT ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["resolutions"], 600))
```